# Create a HTML table with values

Tags: python, html

I have a values like this

```
001/A/1-test-Major-Ø-
001/A/2-test-Critical-●-
001/A/3-yo-Major-Ø-
```

I want to create a HTML table like below for each column:

```
001/A/1   test   Major     Ø  
001/A/2   test   Critical  ● 
.....
.....
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have a think about *why* a `dict` key must be unique.

Comment: It must remove duplicate keys, because that is how a `dict` works. The entire point of it is to associate a value with the key, so that you can check what value corresponds to the key. If you could have duplicate keys, that wouldn't make any sense any more.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. You should try to give more information with your questions. What steps are you taking? What have you tried? Are there some error messages that appear? Also, try adding a bit of code to make your point, or add a link to an external site with an example of your issue. It will improve your chances of being answered.

Answer (score 4):

Python does not support duplicates for dictionaries, maybe try to explain your use case a little bit more.
You can create a dictionary with the same keys but with the values stored in a list. e.g:

```
{'a': ['ajay', 'kumar'], 'sec': [21, 42]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the data into list of tuples

```
a = [{'a': 'ajay', 'sec': 21}, {'a': 'kumar', 'sec': 42}]

a1 = [(k,v) for d in a for k,v in d.items()]
print(a1)
```

output

```
[('a', 'ajay'), ('sec', 21), ('a', 'kumar'), ('sec', 42)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. You can however group multiple values per key, such as using a list.

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a good tool for this.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

a = [{'a': 'ajay', 'sec': 21}, {'a': 'kumar', 'sec': 42}]

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in a:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[k].append(v)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['ajay', 'kumar'], 'sec': [21, 42]})
```

Comment: How to create HTML table in py with values